# Ubuntu gets same IP as another device on the network

Tags: networking, dhcp

I faced with a weird issue. In our office we have wifi and after reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 I am not able to use network due to Ubuntu gets the same ip address as another device(android) has. DHCP is set and I didn't do any custom configuration in the system. After the following commands it gets a unique ip.

```
sudo dhclient -r

sudo dhclient
```

Was trying to solve with  our support team but in their side everything is fine they said. Also manually try to add wifis:dhcp4: yes to netplan config file.

netplan config file:

```
network: 
    version: 2 
    renderer: NetworkManager`
```

Comment: Is mac address the same on both devices?

Comment: no it's not, I don't think the another device is related to the problem. I suppose netplan not works correctly

Comment: what does the netplan config look like?

Comment: @jtessier72 added file to the answer, it's default file created by ubuntu

Comment: I suggest that you remove the connection listed in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` reboot and see if there is any improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed it by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` config file.

added:

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

suppose it uses something else by default